# Turn a dictionary with one key and multiple values into a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary comprised of one key and multiple values.

```py
dict = {'key1':['value1','value2']}
```

I would to take this dictionary and turn it into a pandas dataframe in the following form:

```py
column1    column2
key1    value1
key1    value2
```

Where for every value, key is indicated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
dct = {'key1':['value1','value2']}
pd.DataFrame(dct).melt()
```

Output:

```
  variable   value
0     key1  value1
1     key1  value2
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `pd.DataFrame(my_dict).stack()`?